# DropDownListFor Properties of Collection in ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and was/am not sure exactly how to word my problem.  I have to create a page where the user can add a list of multiple collateral items to a loan application.  Each "row" for each collateral items needs several Dropdownlist to select the type of collateral, its class etc.  The page is based on a ViewModel:

```
public class CollateralViewModel
{
    public Guid LoanApplicationId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CollateralRowViewModel> Collateral { get; set; }
}
```

The IEnumerable Collateral gets the following:

```
public class CollateralRowViewModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public Guid LoanApplicationId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CollateralClass { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CollateralType { get; set; }

        public Guid SelectedCollateralType { get; set; }
        public Guid SelectedCollateralClass { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public decimal? MarketValue { get; set; }
        public decimal? PriorLiens { get; set; }
        public decimal? AdvanceRate { get; set; }

        public string GrantorFirstName { get; set; }
        public string GrantorMiddleName { get; set; }
        public string GrantorLastName { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Create(CollateralViewModel collateralViewModel)
        {
            var collateralServiceProxy = base.ServiceProvider.CollateralServiceProxy;
            var collateralTypes = await GetCollateralTypesByClass(Guid.NewGuid());

            var selectedCollateral = collateralViewModel.Collateral.Select(collateral => new Collateral()
            {
                Id = collateral.Id,
                LoanApplicationId = collateral.LoanApplicationId,
                CollateralTypeId = collateral.SelectedCollateralType,
                Description = collateral.Description,
                GrantorFirstName = collateral.GrantorFirstName,
                GrantorMiddleName = collateral.GrantorMiddleName,
                GrantorLastName = collateral.GrantorLastName,
                PriorLiens = collateral.PriorLiens,
                MarketValue = collateral.MarketValue
            });

            foreach (var collateral in selectedCollateral)
            {
                await collateralServiceProxy.PutCollateralAsync(collateral);
            }
            return View(collateralViewModel);
        }

        private async Task<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> GetCollateralClasses()
        {
            var collateralServiceProxy = base.ServiceProvider.CollateralServiceProxy;
            var collateralClasses = await collateralServiceProxy.GetAllCollateralClassesAsync();

            if (collateralClasses == null)
            {
                return new List<SelectListItem>();
            }
            return collateralClasses.ToSelectList();
        }

        private async Task<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> GetCollateralTypesByClass(Guid collateralClassId)
        {

            var allCollateralTypes = await GetAllCollateralTypes();
            var selectedCollateralTypes = allCollateralTypes.Where(collateralType => Guid.Parse(collateralType.Value).Equals(collateralClassId));

            return selectedCollateralTypes;
        }
```

When I try to use @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Collateral.CollateralClasses) I cannot because CollateralClasses is unavailable.  I type "(model.Collateral." and the properties aren't there.  What am I doing wrong here?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: model.Collateral is an IEnumerable<CollateralRowViewModel>. Its like a collection. first thing you cannot use this like model.Collateral.CollateralClasses, there must be some "FirstOrDefault" to select the property from a single object. Second and most imp question is, where is your CollateralClasses property? i am not able to locate it in the model

Comment: The CollateralClass property is in the CollateralRowViewModel as a IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CollateralClass.

Comment: ok , got it. I was searching it with "CollateralClasses". If the problem is with @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Collateral.CollateralClass) only then it will show suggestion by @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Collateral.FirstOrDefault().CollateralClasses) . Let me know if it works

Comment: I tried that.  It did display the properties, but I still get an error when I type it in like this "@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Collateral.FirstOrDefault().CollateralClass)"

Comment: what is the error? please specify

Comment: views should be for display only and operations limited to controller, my advice would be to make collateralclass a string and then populate it like this:@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Collateral.CollateralClasses, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CollatClass) and on the index or other actionresult that use your view do something like Viewbag.CollatClass= _getCollat.FirstOrDefault(); _getCollat is a property that you set from Database or any other datasource

Comment: Its not clear from the code provided exactly what your trying to achieve. Are you wanting to display a row for each `CollateralRowViewModel` with each row containing dropdowns that are bound to `Guid SelectedCollateralType` and `Guid SelectedCollateralClass` where the choices are based on the collections `CollateralType` and `CollateralClass `?

Answer (score 1):

Please check you dropdownlistfor syntex. I think that may be the issue (because you have not specified the error).Please check the syntex

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContribType, 
                new SelectList(Model.ContribTypeOptions, 
                               "ContribId", "Value", 
                               Model.ContribTypeOptions.First().ContribId))
```

so you may try it like this. In your first place "valueItRepresent", it should be the property for which the dropdown is for

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.valueItRepresent, model.Collateral.FirstOrDefault().CollateralClasses‌ as SelectList, "Select")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your dropdownlist not populated when rendering the UI. You have to properly populate dropdownlist before render data.This can be done in several ways, but I would recommend reading below article.

This [article](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx) provide solution for your question

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this article does not address my issue directly.  I am unable to access the properties needed to create the dropdown because my Model is not setup the same as the example in the article.  I do appreciate your trying to help.